# SQL query to show many/many relationship on a single output?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables in a MS Sql database that I'm trying to join into a single table with a query so I can extract into Excel.

My tables are Person, Industry and PersonIndustry (a join table).

Person has a personId, industry has an industryid, and the PersonIndustry table is simply:

PersonID, IndustryID.

Example records:

People Table:

```
1, John Smith
2, Bob Jones
3. Jill Jane
```

Industry Table:

```
1, Medical
2, Insurance
3, Construction
```

PersonIndustry:

```
1,1
1,2
3,1
```

The output I'd like is:

Personid, name, industry

```
1, John Smith, Medical:Insurance
2, Bob Jones, N/A
3. Jill Jane, Medical
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need all the row from `Person` table `left join` the other two tables.

Then Use `for xml path` trick to Group concat in the result. Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT p.id,
                p.NAME AS p_name,
                i.NAME AS i_name
         FROM   person p
                LEFT JOIN PersonIndustry pin
                       ON p.id = pin.person_id
                LEFT JOIN Industry i
                       ON i.id = pin.indus_id)
SELECT id                                  AS P_id,
       p_name,
       Stuff((SELECT ',' + i_name
              FROM   cte b
              WHERE  a.id = b.id
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS i_name
FROM   cte a
GROUP  BY id,
          p_name
```